# Opening Files with Loop in Python/SPSS

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, concatenation, spss

This is my first time using python with spss. I am hoping to cycle through a handful of files in the same directory, create a new variable, and then save the file. Currently what I have is:

```
begin program.
import spss, spssaux
schools = ['school1', 'school2', 'school3']
for x in schools:
   spssaux.OpenDataFile("C:\...\" + x + "2014.sav")
   school = x
end program.
```

I was hoping this would open each file (school12014.sav, school22014.sav, school32014.sav), and then create a variable called `school` in each file and label every value either `school1`, `school2`, or `school3`, depending on the file name

Let me know if you have any suggestions/questions. Thanks

Comment: So i'm still new to stackoverflow - could someone let me know what about this question led it to be down voted?

Comment: You can use this [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/renaming_vars_Python.htm)

Comment: @Kobi So lets say my first file, `school12014.sav` has three variables `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`. I want to add a fourth variable called `school` and have the value of `school` for all cases in that file to be `"school1"`. does that make sense?

Comment: I've been referencing that link, actually, but I havn't been able to figure it out. I assumed I was doing something pretty obviously wrong and was missing it...

Comment: Oh i think part of my problem is that `school1` and `school2` are actually schools that start with the letter `a` and `b`, which is causing python problems because of the `"\"`

Comment: The `school = x` part doesn't do anything to the actual SPSS data file. You would need to check out the `spss.Submit` command. See this related question, [How can I read in multiple excel files in SPSS using a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14814694/604456). The same advice pretty much extends to this situation whether you want to use Python or the MACRO facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I ended up going with this:

```
begin program.
import spss, spssaux
import os
schoollist = ['brow']
for x in schoollist:
   school = 'brow'
   school2 = school + '06.sav'
   #opens the file
   filename = os.path.join("Y:\...\Data", school2) #In this instance, Y:\...\Data\brow06.sav
   spssaux.OpenDataFile(filename)

   #creates the variable
   cur=spss.Cursor(accessType='w')
   cur.SetVarNameAndType(['name'],[8])
   cur.CommitDictionary()
   for i in range(cur.GetCaseCount()):
      cur.fetchone()
      cur.SetValueChar('name', school)
      cur.CommitCase()
   cur.close()


   spss.Submit("""save outfile="%s".""" % filename)

end program.
```

Comment: lol why was this downvoted? It does exactly what I was hoping to do in the original question

Comment: @MichaelRoland oh ok. I hope my new edits after your advice and Andy's advice are more useful

Answer (score 1):

Remember that \ is an escape leadin so, e.g., \t would be mapped into a tab character.  Either use r (raw) on your path literals as in r"c:\temp..." or use forward slashes.